# Regex for house number

Tags: regex, validation

Looking for a regex that specifies a German house number:

**Valid house number:**

- 12
- 12a
- 12A
- 12 A
- 12 a
- 12 b
- 12 z
- 121 b
- 56/58
- 56/58a
- 56-58
- 56 - 58
- 56-58a

**Not valid house number:**

- 25-ab
- 12ü
- 12_
- 12!"§$$%&/()
- a2
- a2
- 13àâäèéêë
- 0
- 123aaa123,
- 123 aaa 123
- 1 a 1
- 1a 1
- 1a1
- 00 a
- a a
- 00a
- 13àâäèéêëîïôœùûü

Only valid characters are: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

My regex doesn't match the way it should:

`^[1-9]\d*(?:[ -]?(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[1-9]\d*))?$`

Please see my example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i3ddJW/2)

Comment: Try `^[1-9]\d*(?:[ -]?(?:[a-zA-Z]|[1-9]\d*(?:\s*[/-]\s*\d+[a-z]?)?))?$` See https://regex101.com/r/rFKqf6/1

Comment: I'd use `[1-9]\d*(\s*[-/]\s*[1-9]\d*)? ?[a-zA-Z]?`, with anchors around it if you're validating full strings/full lines ([try it here](https://regex101.com/r/8w4ofQ/1))

Comment: @Thefourthbird: the regex in your link works fine! Thank you very much. However, if I copy your regex and paste in into my link the example ``56/58a `` doens't work. Why? Do you use some settings I should know?

Comment: This might help. [`(?i)^[1-9]\d*[-/ ]*\d*[a-z]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/i3ddJW/4)

Comment: @PParker There is a whitespace after it, should it match? You could do it like this https://regex101.com/r/je3p6r/1 or if newlines are also allowed to match https://regex101.com/r/vZujUR/1

Comment: Ah, I did not see the whitespace. Thank you all. Problem was solved by all of you :)

Comment: @Aaron I think your pattern is quite nice and compact. You should make a post out of it.

Comment: @Mandy8055 That also works (note that it could possibly also match `56//` as all is optional)

Comment: @Thefourthbird!!!Got it thanks. Then probably whitespace outside. It boils down to Aaron's answer then or yours.=).

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, done. I put the last two tokens in a group in order to avoid matching trailing spaces when there is no letter at the end.

Comment: Neither `56/58 a` nor `56-58 a` are permitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern that you tried:

- The pattern gets 1 match too many as `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 or more times.
- The pattern is not matching some values because this part `[ -]?` optionally matches a space or a hyphen and the `/` is not present in the character class
- This part `56 - 58` will not match as there is a space and a hyphen to be matched and the optional character class `[ -]?` will match only one of those
- This part `56-58a` will not match, as there are no digits matched before the character class `[a-zA-Z]`

---

As an alternative, a bit shorter variant than I initially commented using an alternation and the case insensitive flag:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?: ?(?:[a-z]|[/-] ?\d+[a-z]?))?$
```

*In parts*

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 and optional digits 0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `?` Match an optional space
  - `(?:` Non capture group (for the alternation)

    - `[a-z]` Match a char a-zA-Z (using case insensitive match enabled)
    - `|` Or
    - `[/-] ?` Match either `/` or `/` with optional space
    - `\d+[a-z]?` Match 1+ digits with optional char a-zA-Z
  - `)` Close non capture group
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` Assert end of line (Or use `\Z` if there can not be a newline following)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1gAqn/1)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following :

```
[1-9]\d*(\s*[-/]\s*[1-9]\d*)?(\s?[a-zA-Z])?
```

It matches :

- a number that starts with a non-zero digit
- optionally, a separator followed by another number starting with a non-zero digit ; the separator can be either `-` or `/` and can be surrounded by space characters
- optionally, a single lowercase or uppercase letter that can be preceded by a space character

If your pattern is supposed to validate full strings or full lines, you might want to enclose it in `^anchors$`.

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/8w4ofQ/2).